# scrollTop not working when I reach a certain div

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am trying to implement on scroll load.

This is my code for on-scroll

```
$(window).on("scroll", function(){
    if( ($(window).scrollTop()-350) + $(window).height() == $(document).height()){

        loaddata();
    }
});
```

I am subtracting 350 from scrollTop because I want the AJAX request to fire on a certain div comes into viewport.

Why is this code not working.

Here loaddata is a function which has an AJAX request.

However, when I run this code, it works:

```
$(window).on("scroll", function(){
    if($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() == $(document).height()){

        loaddata();
    }
});
```

But, I have to go to the end of the page for an AJAX request to fire.

Why is that code not working where I subtract 350 from scrollTop??? I need to fire AJAX when I reach a certain div, how do I do that??

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: I am not able to figure out where am I going wrong.

Comment: If you want any help with debugging, set up a plunkr so the behaviour can be observed

Comment: I don't quite understand your logic, but I'm pretty sure that scrolling to a specific vertical pixel doesn't happen too often. `==` is a very accurate comparison. If you want to understand your problem, **learn how to use a debugger**.

Answer (score 3):

There are two separate issues here; one is that you're testing for an exact scroll position, the other is that you want to be adding 350px to the scroll position rather than subtracting it (so the function will fire 350px before the end of the window, rather than 350px after the end of it.)

Try this:

```
if( $(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() + 350 >= $(document).height()) {
    loaddata();
}
```

But remember that scroll events fire continuously and you probably only want `loaddata()` to fire once! Therefore:

```
var loadedData = false;
$(window).on("scroll", function() {
  if (loadedData) return;
  if ($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() + 350 >= $(document).height()) {
    alert("Fire loaddata now");
    loadedData = true;
    loaddata();
  }
});
```

...and have your `loaddata()` function set loadedData back to false to re-enable the scroll trigger, if necessary.

http://plnkr.co/edit/4QeGuRIdRQ6NchFvUiNt